# Vaildate a Zip code against a list

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to have a form on my intranet site... basically we are a home improvement company and have a list of bad area codes that we do not do business in ... IE list of bad zips 19020 19021 etc are bad so if they are I want it to return with a popup which says bad area ... if it is not on the list I want it to say Good Area

Comment: Well, you've given us something you want, but we can only really help with improving things you already have.  What code have you written to perform this task so far, and where in specific is the code failing?

Comment: And what is your question? And how do you store the list? In an array? In a database?

Comment: I read it as "I don't know how to get started."

Comment: I did not know how to get started but indeed have figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given too much information, so what follows is a very general solution. One way to approach this is to have two maps called `badZips` and `goodZips`:

```
var badZips = {
  "19020": true,
  "19021": true
  ...
};


var goodZips = {
  "90210": true,
  ...
};
```

Then in your form-validation function, you can do:

```
if(badZips[zip]) {
  alert("You entered a bad zip code");
}

else if(goodZips[zip]) {
  alert("You entered a good zip code");
}

else {
  alert("That zip code is not recognized");
}
```

Actually creating the maps depends on how your webapp is set up. How do you store the zips - is it in the database? Or have you hardcoded it?

Answer (score 0):

Using apache, install geoIP. Echo their zipcode into a javascript function, which compares to a black-list you created.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location

Answer (score 0):

Your functional requirements are pretty simple but you didn't really mention what setup you have. Do you want this functionality to happen on a form? What are you going to code with? Do you have a database? Based on the tags you've used I'll just assume that you don't have a database.

Basically you can have a list of area codes and a flag for each to indicate if it's a bad or a good code. You can keep this list in a multi-dimensional array in PHP as static data (http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php).

So it might look something like:

```
<?php
   $areaCodes = array( array('aCode'='19020','aFlag'=>true),
                       array('aCode'='19021','aFlag'=>true),
                       array('aCode'='19022','aFlag'=>false)
                     );
?>
```

When you need an area code to be validated, just do a search in the array and check the flag to see if it's a good code or a bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Store the zip codes in an array, then check if the given zip is in the array.

```
<?php
 $BadZip = array("19020", "19021");

 if (in_array($Zip, $BadZip))
 {
   echo "Bad Zip code!";
 }
?>
```

If in_array returns true, then the zip code is in the list of bad zips.

Alternatively you could use the same method with a list of good zips.